# How can I add the " [boot]" to my spring project after importing from github?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an issue importing where after importing a project from github, somehow not everything is transferred over, as per the screenshot below, anyone idea why this is happening and how I can go about addressing it?

[image: screenshot of issue i'm facing]

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently i needed to select import Maven project as the option rather than just the usual import projects...hope this helps anyone that encounters a similar option in the future